# What statistical test to use?

Tags: computational-statistics

I would like to ask your advice regarding the statistical tools that can be used in analyzing two different kinds of data where  I have to determine if there is an association between them.

For example:
My first type of data is a Likert scale (1-5) to determine the level of participation of the respondents.

My second type of data is a YES or NO data which asks the respondents about their purchasing behavior.

Is there a statistical tool that can be used to determine if there is an association between respondents level of participation and their purchasing behavior given that these are two different kinds of data?

Also, can difference in consumer behavior (like purchasing behavior plus repurchase behavior) be measured between two companies considering that behavior is measured only using YES or NO questions?

Comment: What does your last paragraph mean? Can you clarify your situation?

Answer (score 0):

You might try odds ratio or logistic regression:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

This type of regression deals with categorical data types and could tell you the log odds of your Likert scale (1-5) being returned based on being in the YES or NO response category....